# Two arguments from one input. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, button, input, onclick

Im doing JS exercises. The task is:
 *Write a JavaScript program to check whether two given integer values are in the range 50..99 (inclusive). Return true if either of them are in the said range.*
 Task is easy, I took two numbers from two inputs. 
Is there possibility to take two numbers from only one input? 
and start function like this:

```
function task28(fnum, snum){}
```

Below is mine solution with two inputs.

```
<input type="text" id="task28a" class="form-control" placeholder="write number" aria-label=""
                        aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
<input type="text" id="task28b" class="form-control" placeholder="write number" aria-label=""
                        aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
  </br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm" onclick="task28()">Check</button>
<p class="answer" id="task28ans"></p>
<script>
function task28() {
    let fnum = document.getElementById("task28a").value;
    let snum = document.getElementById("task28b").value;
    if (
        (fnum >= 50 && fnum <= 99) && (snum >= 50 && snum <= 99)
    ) {
        document.getElementById("task28ans").innerHTML = "true";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("task28ans").innerHTML = "false";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: If we place single input for two numbers, then a delimiter is required to identify(separate) two i/p's . Like after space user will enter the second number. then you can do this using same input. The same can mention in the placeholder as message to indicate that to user.

Comment: if as above, the requirement is altered then in task28() you can read value of single input and split the value using space then you will get two number.,..

Comment: thanks. I tried something similar, but I failed. I will try again.

Comment: You may forgot to do parseInt after split..... The split will return two string number..... the greater or less than won't work for those so need to convert to int using parseInt......I added the solution below.. plz check

Comment: thank you :) this time success!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use a form and run a function on submit.
This can also simplify retrieve your values

```js
function DoSubmit(){
  var a = document.myform.myinput.value;
  var b = document.myform.message.value;
  console.log(a,b) 
}
```

```html
<form name="myform" onsubmit="DoSubmit();">
<input type="text" name="myinput" value="" />
<input type="text" name="message" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below code....

```js
function task28() {
    let tempVar = document.getElementById("task28a").value;
    let splitArray = tempVar.split(" ");
    if(splitArray.length == 2)
    {
      let fnum = parseInt(splitArray[0]);
      let snum = parseInt(splitArray[1]);
      if ((fnum >= 50 && fnum <= 99) && (snum >= 50 && snum <= 99)) {
            document.getElementById("task28ans").innerHTML = "true";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("task28ans").innerHTML = "false";
        }
    }
    
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="task28a" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter number" aria-label="" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">

  </br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm" onclick="task28()">Check</button>
<p class="answer" id="task28ans"></p>
```